# Get rsync to work incrementally

Tags: rsync

we have two syslog servers and rsync process between them. The rsync process is run every 15 minutes. We rotate the logs daily, but at the end of the day, there are still dozens of GB of logs - which means the HDD I/O are getting pretty heavy. (I guess because rsync are always syncing whole files)

Its not that there are many log files, just that the log files get pretty big.

Is there a way of how to sync incrementally? Like 'there already are first 100 000 lines of logs, I want to only send last 2000?'

Or could you suggest other improvements of such setup? We currently use 'rsync -avrH' command.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the system is working as designed. The [rsync protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) only sends changes to existing files to the remote file. It does this by determining if the local and remote file timestamps are different. If they are then is reads the local file computing checksums for blocks (as does the remote) and the changed blocks get sent to the remote.

This always requires a complete scan of the file as I don't think that you can exclude sections of it.

If I/O really is a problem to you then I would consider logrotating the logs more frequently. This will mean that once rotated and closed, the file will only be considered for rsync once. The Active log file will also be much smaller so there will be less I/O required to figure out where the changes are.